# Remove duplicate entries in peewee

Tags: duplicates, peewee

I have a quick function that I threw up together to remove duplicates on my table given a particular combination of fields:

```
for l in table.select():
    if table.select().where((table.Field1==l.Field1) & (table.Field2==l.Field2) & ....).count()>1:
        l.delete()
        l.save()
```

But I imagine that there's a better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a unique constraint on the columns you wish to be unique, then let the database enforce the rules for you. That'd be the best way.

For peewee, that looks like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    dob = DateField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('first_name', 'last_name', 'dob'), True),
        )
```

Docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#indexes-and-unique-constraints

Comment: But the columns themselves shouldn't be independently unique. Only a set of columns together should be unique.
EDIT: Ah, would this mean first_name, last_name, and dob all have to be unique for every field? So it's not column independent?

Comment: Just to clarify, this means that I have to drop the table and recreate it correct? Any suggestions as to how to migrate data?

Comment: The code I shared means that first, last and dob should be unique together. So you could have two people named John Smith so long as they had different birthdays. You don't need to drop the table -- you could just run a migration or manually call `create_index()`: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.create_index . Before you create the index, just be sure to remove any duplicates.